# I've got some issues with closePath() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, styles, stroke

I must be to pull a horizontal red and a vertical green line in the middle. I can do it separately for each, but together both lines will be green. Can anyone tell me why?

```
var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

//c.fillRect(20,10,250,175);//

var cw= 450;
var ch= 300;

c.moveTo(0,(ch/2));
c.lineTo(450,(ch/2));
c.strokeStyle= '#db0000';
c.stroke();



c.moveTo((cw/2),0);
c.lineTo((cw/2),cw);
c.closePath();
c.strokeStyle= '#3ac214';
c.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the `beginPath()` method in order to get the colors right. The `beginPath()` method begins a path, or resets the current path.

**Here is the working DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/f0khrmer/

Check updated code here:

```
function drawCanvas(){
    var c= document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');

    var cw= 450;
    var ch= 300;

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(0,(ch/2));
    c.lineTo(450,(ch/2));
    c.strokeStyle= '#db0000';
    c.stroke();


    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo((cw/2),0);
    c.lineTo((cw/2),cw);
    c.closePath();
    c.strokeStyle= '#3ac214';
    c.stroke();
}
```

Hope this helps!